# SQL true/false or either

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server that accepts either a true or false value. Is there anyway to say that it can be true or false and not a fixed value. My table is for a container that can hold hot food or cold food. I want some of the containers to be able to carry hot or cold food depending on an order.

Comment: Add Sample data and expected output

Comment: Also add sample code, where you show how are inserting new items.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a built-in boolean type, so your question doesn't really make sense.  If it is a string, just use `'hot'`, `'cold'`, `'both'`.

Comment: the data type im using is a bit. 0 false(hot) and 1 true(cold)

Comment: I think i will go with the enum solution thanks for the reply's

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has Bit type. Try Something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE yourtablename 
 (
 ID int PRIMARY KEY,
 IsHot bit not null default 1
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try check constraint?
Example code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vendors 
    (VendorID int PRIMARY KEY, VendorName nvarchar (50), 
    CreditRating tinyint)
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Vendors ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Vendor_CreditRating
    CHECK (CreditRating >= 1 AND CreditRating <= 5)
```

This this example we're forcing column CreditRating to store values from 1 to 5. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer really has nothing to do with the question.  In general, I don't downvote, but I would suggest that you delete this.

Comment: Mr @GordonLinoff, the question clearly says "Is there anyway to say that it can be true or false and not a fixed value", I've given him a hint on how he can enforce that by using check constraints. Now it's up to OP how he can use this hint to get a solution. He can use bit datatype and use 0 for false 1 for true or use string just like you suggested in your comment on the question. Now if he's not able to clearly state his problem, all I'm doing is guessing and giving him a hint which also can be a potential solution.